# C++: same code but different output for a linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I've written a program for removing the duplicates in a linked list, but I got different outputs from two online platforms, which are repl.it (using C++) and onlinegdb.com.

```
repl.it -> 10 20 20 30 40 50 (X)
onlinegdb.com -> 10 20 30 40 50 (O)
```

I'm confused about why the output might be different? Is it because of different C++ versions? Or any other reason?

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<stdlib.h>
 
using namespace std;
 
struct Node {
  int data;
  struct Node *next;
}*first=NULL;// declare the helping pointer
 
void create(int a[], int n) {
  int i;
  struct Node *t, *last;
  // create the "first" node
  // with data and the pointer next
  first=new Node;
  first->data=a[0];
  first->next=NULL;
 
  last=first;
 
  // every time, will create a new node
  for(i=1; i<n; i++) {
    t=new Node;
    t->data=a[i];
    t->next=NULL;
    last->next=t; // points to the last node
    last=t; // let the node to be the last node
  }
}
 
void display(Node *p) {
  while(p!=NULL) {
    printf("%d ",p->data);
    p=p->next;
  }
}
 
void removeDuplicateLinkedList(Node *p) {
  Node *q=p->next;
  int x;
  while(q) {
    if(p->data==q->data) {
      x=q->data;
      p->next=q->next;
      delete q;
      q=q->next;
    } else {
      p=q;
      q=q->next;
    }
  }
}
 
int main() {
  int a[]={10,20,20,20,30,40,50};
  create(a,7);
 
  removeDuplicateLinkedList(first);
  display(first);
  printf("\n");
 
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't add the C tag to questions about C++ code.  It annoys people and attracts downvotes.

Comment: i don't see any wrong logic in code ,idk why it is showing wrong output in repl.it

Comment: `delete q;  q=q->next;` doesn't look right to me. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: If something is different on different platforms or compilers, you likely have undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler thanks for reminding me, it won't happen again.

Comment: When you get different output from different compilers 99% of the time it's because of a bug in your code. This rises to 99.99% of the time if you are a beginner. So be realistic and look to yourself for an explanation rather than looking to different C++ versions (at least you didn't try and say compiler bug, as some do).

Comment: And cgigen has pointed out one error, there may be more of course

Comment: @cigien `delete q; q=q->next` This line of code makes the output different. When removing  `q=q->next`, the output is consistently wrong, which is 10 20 20 30 40 50.

Comment: @Woden It's undefined behaviour to use the pointer `q` after deleteing it. The correct way to write that code is to use a temporary variable `Node* t = q->next; delete q; q = t;`.

Comment: Ok. I suggest not focusing on the syntax too much, e.g. by removing one line of code and seeing what happens. I personally find it very helpful to *draw* the links when I'm writing linked list code. Deleting a node means you draw a big cross on it; now it can't be used, e.g. to look at its `next` pointer. When you realize that, you will se that a temporary pointer might be useful, as john has suggested in a comment.

Comment: @john why? If the code is exactly the same, the compiler should return the same error no matter the compiler version, isn't it? Correct me if I'm wrong. Thanks for correcting the code, now it works as expected.

Comment: @Woden No that's not correct. C++ has this concept of *undefined behaviour*. Most programs which break the rules have undefined behaviour, which means that C++ guarantees no particular behaviour from the program. That's exactly what you saw, different compilers produced different results. Only valid C++ programs have guaranteed results.

Comment: @Woden See [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) for some details.

Comment: @john Thank you for the explanation and the link. I'll keep this post to remind myself not to make the same mistake again. Thank all the comments here to help me clarify the concept.

Comment: Feel free to create an answer yourself.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

C++ has *[undefined behaviors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)* when the code is buggy, which means the output won't be necessarily the same even the code is the same. The only possibility that the code generates the different outputs must be the buggy code itself instead of the compiler.

The solution is:

```
void removeDuplicateLinkedList(Node *p) {
  Node *q=p->next;
  int x;
  while(q) {
    if(p->data==q->data) {
      x=q->data;
      p->next=q->next;
      delete q;
      q=q->next;
    } else {
      p=q;
      q=p->next; // wrong here
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, avoid using C tag if asking C++ related question.

Comment: Not an answer! Comments should be given as such!

Comment: Please point out any differences, anything wrong, or write your own. Thank you.

Comment: Your "solution" has the same UB as the OP's.